# extract values with java regex

Tags: java, regex

I begin with regex and i want extract values from a String like this

```
String test="[ABC]Name:User:Date: Adresse ";
```

I want extract Name, User , Date and Adresse 
I can do the trick  with substring and split

```
String test = "String test="[ABC]Name:User:Date: Adresse ";
        String test2= test.substring(5,test.length());
        System.out.println(test2);
        String[] chaine = test2.split(":");
        for(String s :chaine)
        {
            System.out.println("Valeur " + s);
        }
```

but i want try with regex , i did

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("^[(ABC)|:].");
```

but it doesn ' t work

Can you help me please ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

`String#split` is really the best way to accomplish what you are trying to do. Having said that, with regex, the following will give you the same output:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?:\\[ABC\\])([^:]+):([^:]+):([^:]+):([^:]+)$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Valeur " + m.group(1)); // Name
        System.out.println("Valeur " + m.group(2)); // User
        System.out.println("Valeur " + m.group(3)); // Date
        System.out.println("Valeur " + m.group(4)); // Address
    }
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your help , but if i want to negate [ABC] in order to get only Name how can i do that ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for, but I've updated the code so that each group will map to a single element in the original string. Basically, when you wrap an expression with `()`, you *capture* that group, and you can fetch it later with `Matcher`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It work perfectly but the regex became more complicated :p. I need practices so i will read some tutorials about regex . btw thanks you again !

Comment: You'll capture the empty spaces too.  There are some spaces around the address in the example, which I guess you would like to eliminate.  You could fix it with `:\s*([^:]+)\s*$`.  It still keeps the spaces inside the address.  Also, I'm a bit fuzzy about the example: is it really starting with [ABC] or does it include all the rest.   If it's the latter it gets complicated with the start ^ and end $.

Comment: Ok , thanks toto, i will update the code with your advices . Yeah , my String begin with[ABC] , here is an exemple [ABC]STRUTS:PAUL:25/06/2011T10H12:8 Rue Pierre de Coubertin 95300 Pontoise" . I must just extract the values between ":" without [ABC]

Comment: Ok, this will do it then, but I'd stick with the `split` solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the `[` and `]` [here](http://rubular.com/r/kEPQFVFfXS) is a working example.

[`^\[(.*)\](.*):(.*):(.*):(.*)$`](http://%5E%5C%5B%28.%2a%29%5C%5D%28.%2a%29%3a%28.%2a%29%3a%28.%2a%29%3a%28.%2a%29%24)

Note that your code is probably more easily maintained than regular expressions in cases where the regular expression becomes complex.

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems. - Jamie Zawinski

Comment: Thanks for the advice and your citation is really correct but i want juste learn a little regex in order to practice